# Julia types with abstract type and definied type

Tags: types, julia, abstract

How to make type with one abstract and one definied field

Like this:

```
abstract AbstractType 

type type1 <: AbstractType
    x
    y
end

type type2 <: AbstractType
    w 
    z 
end

type MyType{T<:AbstractType}
         a::T
         b::Int64
 end

a = MyType(type1(1,2))
```

I tried with some constructors but it didnt work as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to do. The reason your last statement isn't working has less to do with mixed types and more to do with the fact that you're trying to instantiate your type while missing an input argument.

If you want to be able to instantiate with a default value for b, define an appropriate wrapper constructor:

```julia
abstract AbstractType
type type1 <: AbstractType; x; y; end
type type2 <: AbstractType; w; z; end
type MyType{T<:AbstractType}; a::T; b::Int64; end
MyType{T<:AbstractType}(t::T) = MyType(t,0);   # wrapper
```

```julia
julia> a = MyType(type1(1,2))
  MyType{type1}(type1(1, 2), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was what i want!

Answer (score 1):

You need `MyType` to be a type with just one field, and allow that field to hold a `type1` (or two). That is:

```
type MyType{T<:AbstractType}
         a::T
end
```

Comment: Why is this an issue? Instantiating as `MyType(type1(1,2), 0)` would have worked just fine. I don't think there's such restriction.

Comment: But from the question, it sounded like he wanted to pass it just a single `type1` ("How to make type with one abstract and one definied field"), and was wondering why his command was failing. I agree that the question is very unclear, and I was trying to answer what I thought was the issue.